# A problem with geometric directions

Tags: phrase-usage

Being a native German speaker, I just ran into the following problem: I sit before my desk and...

> A the smoke detector is located above my desk
> B the lamp is located directly above my desk
> C the TV is located right of my desk
> D the door is located directly right of my desk

So mathematically speaking, the desk has some area, and whereas both smoke detector and lamp have a higher y coordinate, their x/z coordinates falls into the desk area for the lamp, but not for the smoke detector.

But...speaking English since 50 years as second language, D sounds off to me!

What do the native speakers say? (Google seemingly has no problems with "directly right of") Also, is the sun directly above my desk (at noon), i.e. does "directly" imply some proximity? And is it rather "directly right to"? (English propositions are a nightmare for?/to? me :-)

Comment: A The smoke detector is higher than my desk.
B The lamp is above my desk.
C The TV is to the right of my desk.
D The door is directly to the right of my desk.

Comment: If A is 'directly above' B, then a line extended upwards from B to A is exactly vertical (_straight up_, at an angle of 90° to the surface or line on which B is standing). No proximity is implied. The length of the line from B to A could be 1 metre or 1 million metres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "I sit before my desk," but it sounds a bit formal or literary.  In order to orient the reader to your position, "I am sitting at my desk" or "I am seated at my desk" both sound more natural to me.

I would say:

A: **The smoke detector is on the ceiling (slightly) ahead of/in front of my desk.**

B: If the lamp is resting on the surface on the desk: **The lamp is on the desk or on top of the desk.**  I would only say the lamp is above the desk if the lamp is suspended somehow, such that there is air space between the top of the desk and the bottom of the lamp.

D: (I'm doing these out of order for a reason!) **The door is directly to the right of my desk.** (Note: It's "directly to the right of," not just "directly right of.")

C: If the door is directly to the right, then I don't understand how the TV is just to the right without being in the doorway.  So I will assume that the TV is on the right side but further away from me than the door is.  In that case, I would say: **The TV is off to the right side from my desk.**  The "off" indicates that, starting at my position, the TV is forward a little bit and then to the right, and "from" sounded better than "of" as it seems to indicate a starting point from which to move forward and rightward to reach the TV. I could also say: **The TV is off to the right side in front of my desk.** or **The TV is at a diagonal to the right in front of my desk.**

Comment: Ah, I even write my thesis in English, but still I haven't learned all the finesses that only a native speaker knows. Your answer was very detailed!